# jquery on click get value undefined

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.nav-li', function () {
    //alert("Clicked");
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    alert(url);
});
</script>
```

---

```
<section style="background-image: url('img/nav-x.png');background-repeat: repeat-x;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                <div class="row">
                    <ul class="col-sm-12 nav">
                        <li href "" style="text-align:center;" class="nav-li">HOME
                            <img src="img/home.png" style="position: absolute;z-index: 100;right: 12px;top: -7px;" class="hrv-img" />
                        </li>
                        <li href "about.php" style="text-align:center;" class="nav-li hvr-bounce-to-top">ABOUT US
                            <img src="img/navhover.png" style="position: absolute;z-index: 100;right: -19px;top: -1px;display: none" class="hrv-img" />
                        </li>
                        <li href "" style="text-align:center;" class="nav-li hvr-bounce-to-top">OUR GROUP
                            <img
```

I need to get the li attribute ("href") value using jquery.. but it alerts "undefined".  Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: if our answers help you then close this question

Answer (score 4):

No issue with your jquery code just update your `href` Attribute  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jnLxynm8/)

NOTE : `href` attribut is not valid for `li` tag.

```
 href"about.php"
 href""
```

to

```
  href = "about.php"
  href = ""
  <li href = "about.php" style="text-align:center;" class="nav-li hvr-bounce-to-top">ABOUT US<img src="img/navhover.png" style="position: absolute;z-index: 100;right: -19px;top: -1px;display: none" class="hrv-img"/></li>
```

you need to add `=` after `href` attribute .

> correct syntax of any attribute of tag is  `Attribute = "value"`

**Secod option**

you can use `data-*` attribute instead of `href`  .ex `data-href="value"`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jnLxynm8/1/)

and update you jquery code

```
<li data-href = "about.php" style="text-align:center;" class="nav-li hvr-bounce-to-top">ABOUT US<img src="img/navhover.png" style="position: absolute;z-index: 100;right: -19px;top: -1px;display: none" class="hrv-img"/></li>


$(document).on('click','.nav-li',function(){
  alert( $(this).data("href") );
});
```

Answer (score 3):

1. `href` attribute on `<li>s` is invalid.

   Use `data-*` attributes.

   ```
   <li data-href="about.php">...</li>
   ```

   or next `li` contents inside an `<a>` anchor

   ```
   <li>
     <a href"about.php">
       ABOUT US
       <img/>
     </a>
   </li>
   ```
2. It should be `href=""` - `attribute="value"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following code

```
jQuery(".nav-li").click(function(event){
    var element = jQuery(event.currentTarget);
    var url = element.attr("href");
    alert(url);
});
```